# Finding Permutations of Strings with no Repeats

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, algorithm

I have posted this question already on this forum [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/162627-implementing-permutations-strings.html), but seeing as no one has answered I decided to try here.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to permute an array of integers given a range with no repeated permutations. I've had trouble understanding how to find permutations in the past, so I was hoping someone could give me an in-depth explaination of what I need to implement and why.

Here is my code as of now :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LENGTH 2

double NumberOfPermuationsOfString( int length, char minimum, char maximum )
{
    return pow( ( maximum - minimum ) + 1, length );
}

int NextPermutation( char * buffer, char minimum, char maximum )
{
    const size_t length = strlen( buffer ) + 1;

    int i = 0;

    for ( ; i < length; ++i )
    {
        /* I don't know what to do here... */
    }

    return 0;
}

void DisplayPermutations( int length, char minimum, char maximum )
{
    char buffer[( length + 1 )];
    memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );
    memset( buffer, minimum, sizeof( buffer ) - 1 );

    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        printf( "%s\n", buffer );
    } while ( NextPermutation( &buffer[0], minimum, maximum ) );
}

int main( )
{
    printf( "Iterating through %0.lf permuations...\n", NumberOfPermuationsOfString( LENGTH, 'a', 'z' ) );
    DisplayPermutations( LENGTH, 'a', 'z' );

    return 0;
}
```

**THIS ISN'T C#, DON'T LET THE NAMING CONVENTION FOOL YOU...**

Comment: What do you mean by "no repeated permutations" ? Do you intend to treat 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 the same ?

Comment: I don't want to have "abc" once, and then appear again later. Also how is this a duplicate? This isn't C#...

Comment: Well, C, but it applies to C++ I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Lippert, author of the [Fabulous Adventures in Coding blog](http://ericlippert.com/), has a good series on [Producing Permutations](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/).

Amongst the explaining, he provides code. For example, the following snippet from [part four](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/25/producing-permutations-part-four/) does what you want *and* allows random access (but uses a custom type):

```
public static Permutation NthPermutation(int size, BigInteger index)
{
  if (index < 0 || index >= Factorial(size))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
  if (size == 0) // index must be zero since it is smaller than 0!
    return Empty;
  BigInteger group = index / size; // What block are we in?
  Permutation permutation = NthPermutation(size - 1, group);
  bool forwards = group % 2 != 0; // Forwards or backwards?
  int insert = (int) (index % size); // Where are we making the insert?                      
  return new Permutation(
    permutation.InsertAt(forwards ? insert : size - insert - 1, size - 1));
}
```

Comment: I'm not doing this in C#... Which means I don't have access to methods like that.

Comment: You should be able to extract the underlying logic and translate it to C++.